# How to get the count and proportion of a single DataFrame column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

Pretty new to Python, so any help is welcome. 
I'm trying to get a count and a proportion of a single column in a DataFrame in Python. I'm wondering what would be the best way to do it.

This works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]})

colCount = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Count','Percentage'])
colCount['Count'] = df['Value'].value_counts()
colCount['Percentage'] = colCount['Count'] / colCount['Count'].sum()
display(colCount)
```

I thought this might work, but the output is not right:

`df.groupby('Value').apply(lambda x: pd.Series( (x.count(), x.count()/len(df)), ['Count', 'Percentage']))`

Output:

```
        Count                   Percentage
Value       
0       Value 11 dtype: int64   Value 0.55 dtype: float64
1       Value 9 dtype: int64    Value 0.45 dtype: float64
```

It is probably very simple, but I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you share expected output?

Comment: I think I found it: `df.groupby('Value').agg({'Value': {'Count': 'count', 'Prop': lambda x: x.count()/len(df)}})`

Comment: I modified your first code, using int() works. `df.groupby('Value').apply(lambda x: pd.Series( (int(x.count()), int(x.count())/len(df)), ['Count', 'Percentage']))`

Comment: Thanks Shimo. Any idea why this works?